# C static variables and forking processes

Tags: c, concurrency, process, static, global-variables

Suppose that I have a static variable initialized globally to zero and I have a process that forks. Now suppose that in this parent process the static variable is set to a value 10. I am noticing in the child process that the static variable is still zero. This behaviour is reasonable because we have not changed the value of this variable in the child process.

How can I get the static variable in the child to be the same value of this variable in the parent? That is, the child's copy of the static variable is also set to value 10.

Thanks and let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: I think `mmap(MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED)` is what you need, but not sure if it is the best possible solution and if it portable/working at all. `shmget` is also relevant.

Comment: You'll need to map the data into shared memory, using the System V IPC (`shmat()` et al), or POSIX (`shm_open()` et al), or `mmap()`.  The parent creates and attaches (or maps) the shared memory, setting a pointer to point to it; the child and parent can then both access the shared memory. Beware synchronization problems. Note that this won't be sharing the global variable per se; it will be sharing the data pointed at by the variable (which might be a global variable). If the child changes the pointer to somewhere else, the parent won't see the change. But both can change shared memory.

Comment: Either assign the variable before you fork, or use IPC

Comment: what if I modify the restriction so that it is not static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that with a static variable you can't, as the memory area in which statics are allocated cannot be shared. Instead, you can create a shared memory area to do this. One way to do this is `mmap` with `MAP_ANONYMOUS` and `MAP_SHARED`. Think of it like `malloc()` except in page sized units. Another route is to use `shm_open()`.